# Proxy for OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken

Tags: oauth, proxy, google-api, gdata, wine

I've setup a perfectly functioning application (in VB) that allows user to access his Google Sheets.

The application follows Google's OAuth documentation for displaying a sign-in dialog in a web browser, obtains user's permission and access codes, uses access codes to obtain access token, and then uses the Google Sheet's Query service to get hold of Google Sheets. Very simple. Works fine.

Problem occurs on computers that have internet proxy defined on them. In the rest of my application and most of Google Sheets API, I can define a manual internet proxy. GData's RequestFactory allows manually configuring proxy server. The only line of code that doesn't support (to my current knowledge) is the OAuthUtil library used for obtaining access token. It doesn't allow defining internet proxy server, hence it is unable to resolve host on computers behind proxy environment. Following is my pseudo code:

```
Dim parameters As New OAuth2Parameters
parameters.ClientId = CLIENT_ID
parameters.ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET
parameters.RedirectUri = REDIRECT_URI
parameters.Scope = SCOPE

>>Show browser window and obtain access code

parameters.AccessCode = login.Token
OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters)    '<< Point of failure

Dim requestFactory As GOAuth2RequestFactory = New GOAuth2RequestFactory(Nothing, My.Application.Info.ProductName, parameters)
requestFactory.Proxy = GetProxySettings()   '<< my code for defining proxy

myService = New SpreadsheetsService("Application")
myService.RequestFactory = requestFactory
```

Another important aspect is that my application works on Mac OSX as well using Wine (for web browser I use GeckoFX). If internet proxy is globally defined on the environment then the OAuthUtil works fine, but this doesn't work for Wine. I have tried setting internet proxy in the command-line environment, or in the registry and refreshed system settings, still the applications running in Wine do not understand that proxy is defined. Hence proxy has to be manually defined.

I need help to figure out a solution by any of the following:
* A way to forcefully/manually define proxy for OAuthUtil for obtaining access token
* Any other way to obtain OAuth access token if proxy cannot be defined as above (maybe WebClient can be used?)
* Some way to define global internet proxy in Wine so applications like GData API read and understand the proxy setting. Though I'd rather prefer manually defined proxy at application level.

Any ideas folks?

Regards
F.A.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. Turns out that the 'OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken' only uses system-defined proxy. There is no way to manually define internet proxy, like RequestFactory supports. So there is a work-around using WebClient:

```
Try
                '// Get access token from code
                Using WC As New WebClient
                    ' Define proxy
                    WC.Proxy = GetProxySettings()
                    ' Set parameters
                    WC.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType) = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    ' Get response
                    Dim postURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
                    Dim postParams = "code=" & parameters.AccessCode &
                                     "&client_id=" & Uri.EscapeDataString(CLIENT_ID) &
                                     "&client_secret=" & Uri.EscapeDataString(CLIENT_SECRET) &
                                     "&redirect_uri=" & Uri.EscapeDataString(REDIRECT_URI) &
                                     "&grant_type=authorization_code"
                    Dim responsebody As String = WC.UploadString(postURL, postParams)
                    ' Read response
                    Dim jObj As JObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responsebody)
                    ' Store token
                    parameters.AccessToken = jObj("access_token").ToString
                    parameters.RefreshToken = jObj("refresh_token").ToString
                    parameters.TokenType = jObj("token_type").ToString
                    parameters.TokenExpiry = Now().AddSeconds(CDbl(jObj("expires_in").ToString))

                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Error obtaining access token: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
                Return Nothing
            End Try
```